# Knockoutjs grid event invoke by code

Tags: jquery, user-interface, knockout.js, grid

I have grid populated as below

```
 <tbody data-bind="foreach : pList">
      <tr data-bind="click: $parent.WClickFunction" >
       <td style='width:5%;' data-bind="text: rolCol"></td>
```

The click event is as below (in ViewModel)

```
self.WClickFunction = function (data, event) {
                     //Code here to highlight the selected row
        };
```

This grid is within a div and this is opened using jquery UI dialog $("#griddiv").dialog("open");

This works fine when dialog loads and I click on any row. Row is highlighed. I want to highlight the first row by default when dialog loads, even without user actually clicking first row. 
How can this be done

Comment: Could you show the code that does all that? Then we can tell..

Comment: You're already highlighting a row via code with your WClickFunction, so I don't see any reason you can't just call WClickFunction() manually.

Comment: Yes Jason, you are correct. I just need to call the function. But what parameters do i pass for data and event. I tried calling function but it gave null exception for data. Do you need WClickFunction code. Let me know.

Comment: Dude, I literally wrote above that I would like to see that code..

Comment: self.WClickFunction  = function (data, event) {
            if (WSelectedRow) {
                WSelectedRow.style.background = 'linear-gradient(180deg, #FFF, #DEDEDE)'
            }
            var element = event.currentTarget;
            WSelectedRow = element;
            if (element) {
                element.style.background = 'rgb(255, 255, 102)';
            }
           
        };

Comment: resolved using DOM :(

Answer (score 0):

resolved using DOM :(. Did not get any other way to access a grid within a jquery UI dialog